# Node.js 'fs.readdirSync' loses directory name for file reading

Tags: node.js

I am attempting to read a directory inside the same directory as my .js on startup. Instead of opening ./open_Bugs/file it goes into ./open_Bugs/ and extracts the file to then attempt and open ./file where I am receiving my error that no such directory exists (because it doesn't), I'm a little lost on how I go about keeping the /open_Bugs/ attached to my read query without doing some awkward appending. Thanks in advance for any help here!

```
fs.readdirSync('./open_Bugs/').forEach(file => {
    fs.readFile(file, function read(err, text){
        if (err) throw err;
        bugArray.push ({
            filename: file,
            info: text,
        })
    })
});
```

This is also my first program I am attempting in node, so I am open to any suggestions on better practices.

Comment: Should be `./open_Bugs` not `./open_Bugs/`

Comment: Also add file's path to readFile `fs.readFile(\`./open_Bugs/${ file }\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design of `fs.readdirSync()` is that it only returns the base filename.  If you want the full path name, you can manually combine that filename with the path you passed to `fs.readdirSync()` because you will always know what it is since it's what you passed as the argument to `fs.readdirSync()`.

You can do that like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

let queryPath = './open_Bugs/';
fs.readdirSync(queryPath).forEach(file => {
    let fullFilename = path.resolve(queryPath, file);
    fs.readFile(fullFilename, function read(err, text){
        if (err) throw err;
        bugArray.push ({
            filename: fullFilename,
            info: text,
        })
    })
});
```

FYI, it's very odd to mix synchronous and asynchronous file I/O functions.  Usually you would pick one model or the other.  In any multi-request server, you would always want to use nothing but asynchronous file operations except during server startup.  In a single user script, you can use the synchronous operations.

Also, you should never write code like:

```
if (err) throw err;
```

inside an asynchronous (non-promise-based) callback.  It does nothing useful except silently hide your error.  Because the callback is asynchronous, the `throw` does not propagate anywhere useful.  You need to write real error handling code (I don't know what you want the error behavior to be).